# unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@2a888da is not valid; is your activity running?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The application uses login and signup from Firebase . After auto-sign in, the app logs in automatically and the app works fine.
But after providing the storage permission, the auto sign in works but it crashes on loading the main activity.

MainActivity.class

```
package com.example.arnav.chatbot;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import org.alicebot.ab.AIMLProcessor;
import org.alicebot.ab.Bot;
import org.alicebot.ab.Chat;
import org.alicebot.ab.Graphmaster;
import org.alicebot.ab.MagicBooleans;
import org.alicebot.ab.MagicStrings;
import org.alicebot.ab.PCAIMLProcessorExtension;
import org.alicebot.ab.Timer;
import com.example.arnav.chatbot.Adapter.ChatMessageAdapter;
import com.example.arnav.chatbot.Pojo.ChatMessage;
import com.example.arnav.chatbot.R;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private ListView mListView;
private FloatingActionButton mButtonSend;
private EditText mEditTextMessage;
private ImageView mImageView;
public Bot bot;
public static Chat chat;
private ChatMessageAdapter mAdapter;
private Student student;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mButtonSend = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
    mEditTextMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_message);
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
    mAdapter = new ChatMessageAdapter(this, new ArrayList<ChatMessage>());

    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mButtonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String message = mEditTextMessage.getText().toString();
            //bot
            String response = chat.multisentenceRespond(mEditTextMessage.getText().toString());
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
                return;
            }
            sendMessage(message);
            mimicOtherMessage(response);
            mEditTextMessage.setText("");
            mListView.setSelection(mAdapter.getCount() - 1);
        }
    });
    //checking SD card availablility
    boolean a = isSDCARDAvailable();
    //receiving the assets from the app directory
    AssetManager assets = getResources().getAssets();
    File jayDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/srm/bots/SRM");
    boolean b = jayDir.mkdirs();
    if (jayDir.exists()) {
        //Reading the file
        try {
            for (String dir : assets.list("SRM")) {
                File subdir = new File(jayDir.getPath() + "/" + dir);
                boolean subdir_check = subdir.mkdirs();
                for (String file : assets.list("SRM/" + dir)) {
                    File f = new File(jayDir.getPath() + "/" + dir + "/" + file);
                    if (f.exists()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    InputStream in = null;
                    OutputStream out = null;
                    in = assets.open("SRM/" + dir + "/" + file);
                    out = new FileOutputStream(jayDir.getPath() + "/" + dir + "/" + file);
                    //copy file from assets to the mobile's SD card or any secondary memory
                    copyFile(in, out);
                    in.close();
                    in = null;
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    out = null;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //get the working directory
    MagicStrings.root_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/srm";
    System.out.println("Working Directory = " + MagicStrings.root_path);
    AIMLProcessor.extension =  new PCAIMLProcessorExtension();
    //Assign the AIML files to bot for processing
    bot = new Bot("SRM", MagicStrings.root_path, "chat");
    chat = new Chat(bot);
    String[] args = null;
    mainFunction(args);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("STUDENT_FILE_KEY", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("student", "");
    student = gson.fromJson(json, Student.class);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        }
    };

    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new 
 IntentFilter(MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.TOKEN_BROADCAST));

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
            }
            else
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                // User is signed out
            }
            // ...
        }
    };

}

private void sendMessage(String message) {
    ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(message, true, false);
    mAdapter.add(chatMessage);

    //mimicOtherMessage(message);
}

private void mimicOtherMessage(String message) {
    ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(message, false, false);
    mAdapter.add(chatMessage);
}

private void sendMessage() {
    ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(null, true, true);
    mAdapter.add(chatMessage);

    mimicOtherMessage();
}

private void mimicOtherMessage() {
    ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(null, false, true);
    mAdapter.add(chatMessage);
}
//check SD card availability
public static boolean isSDCARDAvailable(){
    return Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)? true :false;
}
//copying the file
private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
//Request and response of user and the bot
public static void mainFunction (String[] args) {
    MagicBooleans.trace_mode = false;
    System.out.println("trace mode = " + MagicBooleans.trace_mode);
    Graphmaster.enableShortCuts = true;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    String request = "Hello.";
    String response = chat.multisentenceRespond(request);

    System.out.println("Human: "+request);
    System.out.println("Robot: " + response);
}

}
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.arnav.chatbot">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" 
 />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <service
        android:name="com.example.arnav.chatbot.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <!--<intent-filter>-->
            <!--<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />-->

            <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" 
/>-->
        <!--</intent-filter>-->
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SignInActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Sign-in activity

```
 package com.example.arnav.chatbot;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {

private Button signInButton;
private Button signUpButton;
TextView forgotPasswordTextView;
TextInputLayout emailTextInputLayout,passwordTextInputLayout;
String email;
String password;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private Student student;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

    emailTextInputLayout=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.emailTextInputLayout);
    passwordTextInputLayout=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.passwordTextInputLayout);

    forgotPasswordTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.forgotPasswordTextView);

    signUpButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signUpButton);
    signInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signInButton);

    Toast.makeText(this, SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getToken(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Signing In...");

    signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    signUpButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    forgotPasswordTextView.setOnClickListener(this);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("student");

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, user.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                if (user.isEmailVerified())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this,"arnav",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                            {
                                if (ds.child("email").getValue().equals(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail()))
                                {

                                    student = ds.getValue(Student.class);

                                    String refreshedToken = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(SignInActivity.this).getToken();


Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this,refreshedToken,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    student.setToken(refreshedToken);



  mDatabase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child
("token").setValue(refreshedToken);

                                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
getSharedPreferences("STUDENT_FILE_KEY", MODE_PRIVATE);
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = 
sharedPreferences.edit();
                                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                                    String json = gson.toJson(student);
                                    editor.putString("student", json);
                                    editor.apply();

                                    Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, 
"Sign in " + student.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Intent intent = new 
Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Kindly Verify your 
Email Id first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.signInButton:

            progressDialog.show();

            email = emailTextInputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString();
            password = 
passwordTextInputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString();

            emailTextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
            passwordTextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email))

emailTextInputLayout.setError(getString(R.string.field_cannot_be_empty));
            else if (!isValidEmail(email))

emailTextInputLayout.setError(getString(R.string.invalid_email_id));
            else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password))

passwordTextInputLayout.setError(getString(R.string.field_cannot_be_empty));
            else
            {
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, 
password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                    {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            checkUserExists();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Wrong 
email/password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            break;

        case R.id.signUpButton:
            Intent intent1=new 
Intent(SignInActivity.this,SignUpActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;
        case R.id.forgotPasswordTextView:
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService( 
Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            View alertLayout = 
inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_custom_dialog,null);
            final TextInputLayout emailTextInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) 
alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.emailTextInputLayout);
            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new 
AlertDialog.Builder(SignInActivity.this);
            alert.setTitle("Forgot Password");
            // this is set the view from XML inside AlertDialog
            alert.setView(alertLayout);
            // disallow cancel of AlertDialog on click of back button and 
outside touch
            alert.setCancelable(true);
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            alert.setPositiveButton("Send Email", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {

                    String email = 
 emailTextInputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString();
                    mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
                    Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Password Reset Mail 
has been sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
            dialog.show();

            break;
    }
}


private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();

}

private void checkUserExists()
{
    progressDialog.show();
    final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id))
            {
                FirebaseUser user = 
  FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if (user.isEmailVerified()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, 
  MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Kindly Verify your 
  Email Id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "You need to sign up 
 first...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}

}
```

After providing permission, when I open the app , the auto sign in works but the main activity crashes with the bad token exception- unable to add window. Is your activity running?

here is my logcat:

```
02-27 20:16:33.725 10794-10794/com.example.arnav.chatbot E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.arnav.chatbot, PID: 10794
   android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@7efb1b is not valid; is your activity running?
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:697)
       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
       at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
       at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:459)
       at android.widget.Toast$TN$2.handleMessage(Toast.java:342)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
       at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:107)
```

Comment: post your logcat

Comment: @AbuYousuf done.

Comment: Have you found any solution for that ? I have the same issue..

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignInActivity.this);`
```

Instead of

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);`
```

Go to **Setting** --> Select **Apps** ---> again select setting icon in Apps ---> select draw over other apps

Select your application and enable draw over other apps permition

if that do not work means your dialogs try to show after activity get closed or not on ui thread

Comment: @Radesh here `SignInActivity.this` and `this` are same

Comment: your android api above 21 ? @arnavJJ

Comment: yeah. min 15 , target 26.

Comment: i just found out that the broadcastReceiver , when getting initialized, is not getting activated. i tried a toast in it which didnt display.

Comment: my app is not listed there. I am using Nougat 7.1.1 and the app is in internal storage with permission granted for storage @Radesh

Comment: i have still not found the solution @Radesh,@AbuYousuf,